# hide jQuery Validation error message of Radio Button not work after add custom Radio Button

Tags: jquery, validation

hello i have problem with Jquery Validate . I have radio Button with error handler like this

```
<input name="umum_expectation" type="radio" value="1" required data-msg-required="Please select one" /> 1 <br/>
<input name="umum_expectation" type="radio" value="2" />2<br/>
<input name="umum_expectation" type="radio" value="3" />3<br/>
<input name="umum_expectation" type="radio" value="4" />4<br/>
<input name="umum_expectation" type="radio" value="5"  />5<br/>

<!-- handler show error-->
<label for="umum_expectation" class="error"></label>
```

and i customing radio button with iChek >> https://github.com/fronteed/iCheck/

and this code customize

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
              $("input[type='radio']").iCheck({
              checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
              radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue',
              increaseArea: '20%'
            });
            });
        </script>
```

**before i customing radio button**, when i push submit button without not checking radio button, the  error displayed. then i checking radio button , **the error can automatically hide**.

**current condition**, when i push submit button without not checking radio button, the  error displayed. then i checking radio button , the error cannot not automatically hide. **This must push submit button again to hide error**

so how to fix it like condition before i customed radio button ? sorry for my english

Comment: Hello, Did you find solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

By default, jQuery Validate ignores hidden input elements.

Simply tell the plugin not to ignore the hidden element (which is what happens when you intialize iCheck):

```
$('form').validate({
    hidden:'',
    //the rest of your options
});
```